# Fixing Google text loading in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am getting an error on google speed check about 'Ensure text remains visible during webfont load' that I am trying to fix.

In my functions.php file there is the following code -

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'ffe-child-theme-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700');
```

So this is obviously pointing to a file where the @font-face is specified.

How do I optimise this to get rid of the error?  I think I need to add &display=swap somewhere I believe?

Should I add the @font-face code directly to my site somewhere rather than using a url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a default system font which is commonly available. Then text can be rendered while the font loads.

```
body {
  /* While Source Sans Pro loads, sans-serif is used. */
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
```

You **should not** include the `@font-face` code because you cant know if it will change or not.

Comment: Thanks.. I already have the following in my custom.css file.. should I add something to it?  - body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important; }

Comment: Is the your css file loading? Are the styles maybe overriden later by another rule?

Comment: Yeah the file is loading.. the only mention of font-family is source sans pro.. so i'm really not sure. I don't know what to do to fix this 'Ensure text remains visible during webfont load'  error